# Excel - Shading entire Column based on one value

Tags: excel, calendar, conditional-formatting

i am trying to make a work calendar for myself. [screenshot of the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osKDa.png)

I have written a conditional formatting to color all saturdays and sundays with the following code

=OR(WEEKDAY(B2)=2,WEEKDAY(B2)=1)

how can i make the Entire column under that day be colored.

Thanks :)

Comment: Select the whole column, and apply the conditional formatting with B$2 instead on B2.

Comment: I'm puzzled by this whole question because the WEEKDAY function returns 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday by default (not 1 & 2), unless you call it as WEEKDAY(B$2,16) - or am I missing something?

Comment: $ or relative reference worked :) Thanks to everyone. @TomSharpe WEEKDAY function is returning weekends for 1,2. I think it has to do with the calendar settings, for the day the week starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to be moving columns around (`Friday` will always be in whichever cell it is at present and days just continue in sequence to the right) it might be easier to select the entire range to be subject to formatting and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(MOD(COLUMN(),7)=3,MOD(COLUMN(),7)=4)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Adjust `3` and `4` to match whichever day you choose to start the sequence with wherever your selected range starts.

Given information you have withheld of what is where the above might be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

In Conditional formatting | Use a formula...

```
=WEEKDAY(B$2,16)<3
```

extended from B2 down and across.

Comment: =WEEKDAY(B$2)<3 works. Why did you add the return type as "16" ?

Comment: According to the reference https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a adding 16 Numbers 1 (Saturday) through 7 (Friday) so means that you can have one condition (<3) for weekends instead of more than one..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a relative cell reference on B2:

`=OR(WEEKDAY(B$2)=2,WEEKDAY(B$2)=1)`

Here's an article about using relative references in conditional formatting: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/07/relative-absolute-cell-references-excel-conditional-formatting/

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thanks. I was using the wrong syntax.